# Application Map - software and / or method suggestion

Tags: applications, sitemap, representation, presentation

We are developing a very large application and we need to map it for executives to be able to understand and follow the process. I am not making a mind-map like network visual on prezi (sorry I can not share since it is confidential) but the doc will need to be updated and detailed for a long time. So it will live with us for the coming 2 years at least.

Does anyone have experience in such a presentation document? Any software or method suggestion?

Comment: What I am looking for is more of a tool to show developers and the head of the IT company the elements and links of the whole system. More of a blueprint...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a customer/user journey map that focuses in this case on the 'journey' that the user is taking on the application. It's a rich visualisation of the process and touch points which works great in groups.

There are loads out there on journey maps, but a good place to start is at:
[User Jourenys - The Beginner's Guide](http://theuxreview.co.uk/user-journeys-beginners-guide/)

> What is a user journey?
>
> A user journey is a series of steps (typically 4-12) which represent a
>   scenario in which a user might interact with the thing you are
>   designing. They can be used for 2 main things:
>
> Demonstrating the way users currently interact with the service /
>   website / product Demonstrating the way users could interact with the
>   service / website / product

**Important to note:** A Customer/User journey maps is a very valuable tool to use not only on the application in this case, but zoom out to see the whole 'journey' that captures the true experience that the user has when engaging with your company.

More useful reading: [The Value of Customer Journey Maps](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2011/09/the-value-of-customer-journey-maps-a-ux-designers-personal-journey.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Adriaan. What I am looing for is more of a tool to show developers and the head of the IT company the elements and links of the whole system. More of a blueprint... The resources look very good; I will definitely use them in other projects.